# return nested hours of operation in a postgresql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of garages. I am allowing for an API query that should also be able to return the hours of operation for the garages. The hours of operation are related to the garage in a TimeBlock table.

TimeBlock Table:

- open_at
- close_at
- day_of_week (0-6)
- is_24hr
- is_closed
- garage_id

This is my current query. Is there any way to enhance it to also return the 7 TimeBlock entries per Garage table?

```
select g.name, bool_or(c.garage_id is not null)
from
    garage g
    left join
    car c on g.garage_id = c.garage_id
group by g.name
```

### Example of data:

---

### GarageA (id=10)

name = "gA"

TimeBlock:

- open_at = 800
- close_at = 2000
- day_of_week = 0
- is_24hr = false
- is_closed = false
- garage_id = 10

TimeBlock:

- open_at = 800
- close_at = 2000
- day_of_week = 1
- is_24hr = false
- is_closed = false
- garage_id = 10

etc. (x7)

### GarageB (id=20)

name = "gB"

TimeBlock:

- open_at = 800
- close_at = 2000
- day_of_week = 0
- is_24hr = false
- is_closed = false
- garage_id = 20

TimeBlock:

- open_at = 800
- close_at = 2000
- day_of_week = 1
- is_24hr = false
- is_closed = false
- garage_id = 20

etc. (x7)

Thanks!

Comment: So 1 timeblock entry per day of week, 7 timeblock entries per week?  What you are looking for is 'pivot' to pull out the 7 days of the week on to one line...give the term 'pivot' a search, there's usually 4 or 5 of these questions on here per day.

Comment: It will help if you could provide sample data and expected results. Consider using sqlfiddle.com for this.